# touchesEnded is not calles when table is scrolled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, three20

I have a `TTTableViewController` table , with `TTTableLinkedItemCell`cells.

In the cell I have `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` function.

This function is called only when the table is clicked, but not when it is scrolled. 
Is there some other function that interceps the scrolling?

Comment: As the name suggests touchesEnded will only be called when your touch on the screen ends. So when scrolling, Function name touchesMoved should be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIGestureRecognizer to recognize certain actions like tap, move, rotate and scale.
Please find the below url
http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/

Comment: Thank you!
I used the following function from the tutorial:

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
//function is entered after scroll 
//my code    
}